# How to change background color of NSSearchField (like in Messages app in OS X)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

I need to get this appearance of NSSearchField

[image]

But it seems to be impossible to set backgroundColor with standard methods of Interface Builder. How i can achieve this? 
Subclassing NSSearchField and NSSearchFieldCell didn't help, because i loose all animations (when you click on search field and icon+text sliding to left) when implementing my own draw methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What your screenshot shows is just the standard look of `NSSearchField` when being placed under an `NSVisualEffectView`. That is, the search field will automatically get the look above when it's a subview of `NSVisualEffectView` (with the `material` of `NSVisualEffectMaterialLight`).

However, if you want this appearance without `NSVisualEffectView`, you can manually set its appearance:

```
searchField.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight];
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my god... That is. Thank you very much! I see no way that I would have guessed to look into NSVisualEffectView.

Comment: Do i have a way to change colour of background to lighter?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot customize the appearance of `NSTextField` without touching the layer (as @Ckouta suggested in another answer) or subclassing it. If you are feeling you must customize it, I would suggest the subclassing way.

Comment: Subclassing loose animations, i don't know why. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. I just overrided drawFrame or draw method and text with icon looses their animations on search field click.

Comment: Also i discovered that  `self.searchField.appearance = NSAppearance(named:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight );` method and `NSVisualEffectView` (changed to vibrant light) are giving various results - in first case i got lighter colour.

Comment: Well, under an `NSVisualEffectView`, `NSTextField` will change its fill color to reflect the background color (just as `NSVisualEffectView` does), so its color may vary a little at different situations. Regarding subclassing, it seems that `-drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` of `NSTextFieldCell` handles the animation, but I am not quiet sure about how to implement this method while preserving the animation. That's another question.