# How to get the vibrant effect for a NSTextField/NSSearchField like Safari's address bar in Big Sur

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, macos-big-sur, nssearchfield, nsvisualeffectview

I have a Mac app with a search field in its toolbar (actually a `NSTextField`, but I tried `NSSearchField` as well).

My problem is that the text field background on Big Sur is just plain white, which makes it hard to recognize.

Safari's location bar on Big Sur has more contrast. I believe this is somehow achieved by using vibrancy ([How to change background color of NSSearchField (like in Messages app in OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30287662)), but I cannot get the same effect.

[image: Title bars]

I tried:

- `testTextField.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantLight)`
- various combinations of drawing/not drawing backgrounds
- various background colors
- wrapping my toolbar item into `NSVisualEffectView`, but that shows around the text field

Edit:

I should mention that I use `roundedBezel` border style. This alone seems to affect the background color (i.e. background is always white, no matter which color was set).